# Load user control dynamically on Button Click

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I have a label and a text box which i have added in the user control.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddMultiLoc.ascx.cs" Inherits="CRM_Streamline_Forms.UserControls.AddMultiLoc" %>
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="width:25%">
        <asp:Label ID="lblLocName_UC_G0138" runat="server" Text="Location Name:" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocName_UC_G0138" runat="server" Width="200px" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%">
        <asp:Label ID="lblLocID_UC_G0138" runat="server" Text="Location ID:" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocID_UC_G0138" runat="server" Width="200px" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have a link button in one of my aspx pages which is when clicked should populate this user control.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddLoc_AGBI2_G0138" runat="server" Text="+ Add Another Location" onclick="lnkAddLoc_AGBI2_G0138_Click" />
```

Code behind, I have written this code for the button click:

```
protected void lnkAddLoc_AGBI2_G0138_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddMultiLoc con = (AddMultiLoc)LoadControl("~/UserControls/AddMultiLoc.ascx");
        pnlMultiInvoiceInfo1_AGBI2_G0138.Controls.Add(con);
        Panel p = new Panel();
        Control uc = (Control)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/AddMultiLoc.ascx");
                    p.Controls.Add(uc);
                    p.Width = 200;
                    p.Height = 100;
                    pnlMultiInvoiceInfo1_AGBI2_G0138.Controls.Add(p);
    }
```

First time the user control is populated as am calling it in the aspx page, but second time when i click on the link button, it is not populating the user control for the second time. Am new to coding, please help :(

Comment: I have provided a working example below. Any update on this?

Comment: I replied on ur answer am sorry...I cannot use session as these pages will be hosted on the CRM and CRM is stateless...I was told not to use session objects :(

Comment: Thanks. You really should have posted that information originally.

Comment: I am so sorry..My apologies, am new to these forums and i do mistakes and i understand it now. Will be careful next time.. :(

Comment: No need to apologise. Why don't you just post your code that you said is working and share the information with the rest of us. Also, you should mark your questions answered when you receive a correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is that you are losing your controls across postback as the controls are loaded in to the ViewState.

Here is a sample where you can load the controls in to the Session which is not really good practice but it will work for your purposes:

**AddMultiLocPage.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddLoc_AGBI2_G0138" runat="server" Text="+ Add Another Location" OnClick="lnkAddLoc_AGBI2_G0138_Click" />
        </div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Placeholder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**AddMultiLocPage.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class AddMultiLocPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadControlsFromSession();
    }

    private List<AddMultiLoc> ViewStateControls
    {
        get { return (List<AddMultiLoc>) Session["ViewStateControls"]; }
        set { Session["ViewStateControls"] = (List<AddMultiLoc>)value; }
    }

    private void LoadControlsFromSession()
    {
        if (ViewStateControls != null)
        {
            Placeholder1.Controls.Clear();

            foreach (var c in ViewStateControls)
            {
                Placeholder1.Controls.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void lnkAddLoc_AGBI2_G0138_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var con = (AddMultiLoc)LoadControl("~/AddMultiLoc.ascx");
        con.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        List<AddMultiLoc> tmpList = ViewStateControls;
        if(tmpList == null) tmpList = new List<AddMultiLoc>();
        tmpList.Add(con);
        ViewStateControls = tmpList;

        LoadControlsFromSession();
    }
}
```

**UserControl Markup**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            <asp:Label ID="lblLocName_UC_G0138" runat="server" Text="Location Name:" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocName_UC_G0138" runat="server" Width="200px" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            <asp:Label ID="lblLocID_UC_G0138" runat="server" Text="Location ID:" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocID_UC_G0138" runat="server" Width="200px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My prob is i cannot use session as these pages are going to be hosted in CRM and CRM is stateless...Please explain...

Comment: @user1742152 That information should have been in your original post!

Comment: I am sorry about that. I got a work around, will post it soon.

Answer (score -2):

No need to store control in session, Solution to your problem is :

ASPX Code :

```
< asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddLoc_AGBI2_G0138" runat="server" Text="+ Add Another Location" onclick="lnkAddLoc_AGBI2_G0138_Click" />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
```

Code Behind :

```
protected void lnkAddLoc_AGBI2_G0138_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control uc = (Control)Page.LoadControl("~/AddMultiLoc.ascx");
        Panel1.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
```

Any time you click on link button lnkAddLoc_AGBI2_G0138 it add new instance of User Control to Panel1.

Comment: This does not work for me given your code and his combined. Have you tested this? Can you give a complete working example?

Comment: This is perfectly working example. In my code user control is created in the root of application. You need to change the path of user control in LoadControl("~/AddMultiLoc.ascx") call and do not merged my posted code with any other code it must work as working fine here.

Comment: Ok. Post all of your code then. i.e. your web form, code-behind and user control and code-behind and let's see this working example.

Comment: Hi it worked pretty well, but only for the first time. Second time i click on the add another location link button, it does not do anything...

Comment: @Seany84 : I don`t think there is any need to post full webform code as there is no extra code except the default code generated by framework,only the code posted by me is enough to solve problem that user control disappears after second click.

Comment: @user1742152 : As you mentioned in your question that after second click of button your user control disappears, in the solution i provided you user control does not disappears on second click. Can you brief exact scenario you want to develop so that i can provide you the exact solution.

Comment: @GauravRajput -1 I think the problem here is that you don't understand the question. The OP wants to dynamically add the user control to the page each time the button is clicked. So, if it is clicked 4 times there will be 4 user controls added dynamically to the page. Your code only adds it on first click and does not work subsequently. This is why I asked for a full code sample.