# How to refresh Web Usercontrol on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a web user control on an aspx page for displaying the locations on a google map into which I am passing locations as parameters from ASPX page load event and whenever the page is loaded I am getting the locations perfectly.

I have to change the locations whenever user searches for a particular location on clicking the "Search" button ion the ASPX page and i am passing the locations to web user control in the "search" button click event but unable to get the locations onto the web user control.

```
public partial class MapControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public List<string> MyLocation {get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GeoCode geocode;
        List<GMarker> markers = new List<GMarker>();
        for (int i = 0; i < MyLocation.Count(); i++)
        {
            geocode = GMap1.getGeoCodeRequest(MyLocation[i]);
            GLatLng gLatLng = new GLatLng(geocode.Placemark.coordinates.lat, geocode.Placemark.coordinates.lng);
            GMap1.setCenter(gLatLng, 20, GMapType.GTypes.Normal);
            GMarker oMarker = new GMarker(gLatLng);
            markers.Add(oMarker);
            //GMap1.Add(oMarker);
            GListener listener = new GListener(oMarker.ID, GListener.Event.click, string.Format(@"function () {{ var w = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); w.setContent('<center>{0}</center>'); w.open({1}, {2});}}", "<b>" + MyLocation[i] + "</b>", GMap1.GMap_Id, oMarker.ID));
            GMap1.Add(listener);
        }

        GMap1.Add(new GMapUI());
        GMap1.GZoom = 10;

 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 List<string> locations = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    Label addressline1 = (Label)this.ListView1.Items[i].FindControl("addr1");
                    string addrloc = addressline1.Text;
                    locations.Add(addrloc);
                }
                MapControl mc = LoadControl("~/MapControl.ascx") as MapControl;
                mc.MyLocation = locations;
}
```

And i included this web user control into Search.aspx file and and when i passed locations from page load event its working but when i tried to pass locations from search button click event getting Null value into Mylocations value of Web user control as null.. so Is there any way to to reload the User control with newer locations.

Comment: Can you post us the code ? And use "ispostback" in page load event

Comment: What had you try so far to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use here updatepanel. You have to keep google map into update panel and set trigger against this button to your map. Then I think you will get what you want. If any confusion pls let me know

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the reply I had kept google map in a web user control and as you have said i had kept user control in update panel also along with triggers but I am unable to pass the locations in this web user control on button click.. As if we see asp page life cycle events **Control events** will be fired  after the **Load** event of the page so that user control is loaded before the button click event and stops me to pass location values... Is there any way to load the user control after button click with newer values

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207174/load-user-control-dynamically-on-button-click)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207174/load-user-control-dynamically-on-button-click            Go to this link. This might be helpful to you.